# Modifying a link while dragging it to the bookmarks toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarks

I have this nested, Bootstrapped accordion where the collapsing is done [by setting the element href's as "#collapseOne", "#collapseTwo"](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) and so on.

On my page, when user clicks a link on the accordion the page also loads the content as specified by the anchors "`data-guid`" attribute such as:

```
//HTML
<a href="#collapseOne" data-guid="Cats">Click to fill page with cats</a>

$(".link_to_click").on("click", function(){
    var guid = $(this).data("guid") // cats
    loadContent(guid) // loads cats to page
});
```

I want to bookmark this page by dragging the link to the bookmarks toolbar (Firefox) and I get this

[Cats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8Gm2.png)

When I'd like the location to be www.catsforall.com/index.html?guid=cats

If I try to change the href when starting the drag

```
$(".link_to_click").on("dragstart", function(){
   $(this).prop("href", "www.catsforall.com/index.html?guid="+$(this).data("guid"));
});
```

it still bookmarks the **original href** even though it changes the href in the element and the dragend event also says it has been changed.

```
$(".link_to_click").on("dragend", function(){
   console.log($(this).prop("href")); // www.catsforall.com/index.html?guid=cats
});
```

I have also been trying to change "pathName"-property and tried to fiddle with event.originalEvent.dataTransfer objects with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you Drag and Drop something, you dont move or alter The original object. A copy is written down is the buffer.

As Im no expert id try the following:

```
event.dataTransfer.getData()
event.dataTransfer.setData()
```